# how to use conditional statement in Pug

Tags: html, pug, web-frontend

I have the following PUG code I want to use the **if** statement so that  I will print the submit button using the **for** loop

```
html
    head
        title test
        link(type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css")
        meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    body
        -inputTypes = ['text','email','password','password']
        -placeholders = ['username','email','password','confirm password']
        -values = ['submit']
        div.cont_login
            center
                img(src="images/user.png")
                form(method="post" action="index.html")
                    for i in [0,1,2,3]
                        input(type=inputTypes[i] placeholder=placeholders[i])
                    input(type="submit" value="submit")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for an if statement in PUG:

```
  if condition
    code
  else if condition2
    code2
  else
    code3
```

In your case, you will want to check if i is the last iteration (3), then print the submit input if so.

Comment: Thanks, it was useful